# Can I use SONY MDR-ZX770AP as microphone in Skype?

Tags: windows-10, skype, microphone, headphones

I buy headphones [SONY MDR-ZX770AP](http://www.sony-asia.com/electronics/headband-headphones/mdr-zx770ap/specifications). From specification:

> In-line remote and mic for hands-free calls
>
> With an in-line remote and built-in microphone on the headphone cord,
>   you can take hands-free calls from selected smartphones while
>   listening to music. Switch easily between songs and calls with no need
>   to remove your headphones.

Can I use this mic for skype calls? I want it, but there is no such mic option in Skype settings:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this setup working? I'm looking for the same thing with the Sony MDR 1A headphones

Comment: @Brian yeah, I just bought the adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends more on the computer. If you have a dual headphone and microphone socket, it should just work (It probably won't list another entry, the sound driver will be responsible for swapping between the inbuilt microphone and the external one if it detects an external connection).

However, if you have two separate sockets, one for headphones and one for a microphone, you will need a splitter cable like this:

[image]

<sub>3.5mm female 4 pole TRRS to 2x 3.5mm male 3 pole TRS adapter</sub>

Note that the green male end would go to a headphone/speaker socket, and the red end to a microphone socket. Some headsets use different configurations, so you may need to research exactly what adapter you need.

Comment: thank you for answer. I have common laptop with two different ports. So, can I buy this adapter and use my headphones as micro?

Comment: @Denis Yes, that should work fine.